# Yii2-mongodb how to query for MongoDate

Tags: yii2

I use Yii2-mongodb extenstion, I want to query items of today. When use new MongoDate($sometime), got an error: Class 'common\models\MongoDate' not found

```
$query = new \yii\mongodb\Query;
$issues = $query->select(['no', 'end'])
                ->from('issue')
                ->where(['end' => ['$lt' => $end]])
                ->orderBy(['end'=>SORT_ASC])
                ->all();
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Looks like you don't have the [mongo php extension](http://php.net/manual/de/mongo.installation.php) installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii2 is fully namespaced and MongoDate is part of the global namespace. That means you should address it as such: `new \MongoDate($sometime)`

(I'm assuming you actually have the extension installed here :) )